# whatsApp - profile pic can't be seen last seen info can be

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, ios

strange question here:

I can see someone's "last seen info" and there are 2 ticks when my message to that person is delivered but suddenly the profile picture is no longer seen by me.

Does it mean that person deleted my number from "my contacts" in her phone or just deleted her last profile pic and at the moment she hasn't got any to show.

we both have the last version of the application that is being run - in both cases - on iphone6

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this question can be answered correctly but I'll take my chances. We can't actually know any better than you would. One of the followings can be the case:

- She might have deleted her profile picture.
- She might have deleted you from her contacts (with her privacy settings for profile picture: *My contacts* or *Nobody*)
- She might have changed her privacy settings for profile picture to *Nobody*

Comment: Thanks, but still - if I was deleted from "my contacts" - would I still be able to see "last seen" and "offline/online" info ?

Comment: @robot Depends. If the said person set their privacy settings to *everyone* then yes you would see them regardless of your existence in their "My contacts"